# There is some error while signing in PlatformException(ERROR_ADMIN_RESTRICTED_OPERATION, This operation is restricted to administrators only., null)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm new in firebase I am trying to authenticate user by using anonymous authentication of firebase but it giving the following error.

[image: here is the error screenshot.]

The example code is here:

Authenticating dart file.

```
class AuthServices {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //sign in method.
  Future signningAnon() async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;
      return user;
    } catch (e) {
      print("There is some error while singing $e");
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Main file:

```
void main() {
  AuthServices _auth = AuthServices();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'chekcing firbase authentication',
    home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Firbase authentication"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Text('click me'),
            onPressed: () async{
              print("object");
              dynamic result = await _auth.signningAnon();
              print('result is $result');
            },
          ),
        )),
  ));
}
```

here is yaml dependency file.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  toast: ^0.1.5
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  timeline_list: ^0.0.3
  font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
  carousel_slider: ^1.3.1
  photo_view: ^0.8.0
  url_launcher: ^5.4.1
  get_it: ^3.1.0
  flutter_compass: ^0.3.4
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3 // here is firebase dependency.
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
```

If, someone has a solution please help.

Comment: where is the code?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the exact error message and stack trace?

Comment: I have the same error. Still couldn't find an answer

Answer (score 23):

You need to add the anonymous sign in option in the Firebase Authentication section of the console. Where you have setup your project.

Answer (score 13):

You need enable Anonymous sign-in provider.

1. Go to Firebase
2. Go to Authentication
3. Enable Anonymous

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Besides enabling Anonymous Sign-In method like several people already answered before me, make sure to check `Enable create (sign-up)` in the `User actions` section of the Authentication Settings of the Firebase console.

[image: Firebase Console Authentication Settings]